# Power Automate to Generate Notifications re: PBI Workspace Access Changes

Tags: powerbi, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

Can Power Automate be used to generate notifications about Power BI workspace changes such as: 1) adding/removing a user from a workspace; 2) updating user roles or permissions within a workspace; 3) Creating or deleting a workspace?

We're trying to come up with efficient ways to monitor these types of activities and were told Power Automate might be a solution. Thank you!

Comment: If there’s a REST API for the things you want to monitor then yes, it would be an ample tool to use.

Comment: I don't think there are any triggers in power automate for power bi workspace changes. I think there is a power bi rest api so I guess you could set up a scheduled power automate flow that checks for changes and emails if there are any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Power BI REST API - [Admin - Get Activity Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/get-activity-events).

Then in Power Automate, you can query this API call at regular intervals with the relevant filters. See [Call Power BI Rest APIs with Power Automate](https://www.vahiddm.com/post/call-power-bi-rest-api-with-power-automate).